# SQL & C# Search for a record and expect a record or a set of records?

Tags: c#, sql

This might seem subjective, but I'm looking for answers from those who like to set, or at least be a part of setting, coding standards.

In C#, What type of result should you expect when searching for a single record by a non primary key index?

If you :

```
select * from tablename where fieldname=@fieldname
```

*As a matter of practice*, should you code logic to expect an IEnumerable list or a single record?

If you really expect only one record, should the SQL use TOP 1? like below:

```
select Top 1 * from tablename where fieldname=@fieldname
```

Comment: What would contain a single record that is not also (in some way) enumerable? - and is therefore something you can read() to get the first row, then choose if you want to ensure there is no more data and deal with that potentially serious problem as required.

Comment: True, any single item can always be represented in a list of its type. Is that good to think of this as a *standards frame of mind*? Would that pass muster, so to speak?

Comment: @naathon - when looking for a user by email, there are no other criteria to apply.

Comment: I guess it boils down to how much trust you have in the system you are talking to and the consequences of their being unexpected duplication

Comment: So trust the system and unique indices, and don't code to the nth dimension of possibilities? 80/20 rule... I was thinking more of none unique indices, but I get your point.

Comment: @naathon - there is no email unique index in Identity 2.0, and if you customize UserStore, you have to account for looking up existing emails on new registrations...all normal to watch out for, but then, do we need no safeguards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think rather than thinking about what you *expect*, a better way to look at this is construct your query such that you get what you *want*.  If you are only interested in the zero or one potential matches then TOP(1) certainly works.  Although I'd likely add some type of ordering clause.

However, if you want zero or more, then the first approach is better.

Any time you are querying based off of a non-unique value you always have the possibility of returning more than one record.  Sure, today that query only gets one.  However at some point in the future an unforseen change will occur and all of a sudden you now get multiple rows back.

Comment: "You can't always get what you want" (I can't sing, but...) Well, then if more than 1 record could be construed as an application error, that condition can be logged and thrown to avoid issues compounded by that state?

Comment: @RobertAchmann:  It could, but the real question is whether that actually constitutes an actual error or not.  If it does, then perhaps the column should be part of the unique key for the record.